# Access docker-compose volume from host masine (copy files "into" container and acces contailer-files from outside)

Tags: docker, docker-compose, volume

I'm trying to run **jira** from docker compose (as of now this would not be necessary but later on I will add additional services). So far almost everything works.

```
version: '3'
services:

  jira-local-standalone:
    container_name: jira-local-standalone
    image: atlassian/jira-software:8.5.0
    volumes:
      - ./work/jira-home:/var/atlassian/application-data/jira
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    environment:
      TZ: Europe/Berlin
      JVM_RESERVED_CODE_CACHE_SIZE: 1024m
      JVM_MINIMUM_MEMORY: 512m
      JVM_MAXIMUM_MEMORY: 2048m
    networks:
      - jiranet

networks:
  jiranet:
    driver: bridge
```

The only thing that does not work is this: I want the **jira** home to be accessible via the file manager on my host nachine. To access logs etc. and to "upload" import files. So I want to copy the files to the specified location on my host and be available to `jira` inside my container. More or less like some sort of a shared folder.

I expected the directory **./work/jira-home** to be populated during startup (creating the **/var/atlassian/application-data/jira** inside **./work/jira-home** and write **logfiles** and stuff). But the **./work/jira-home**  folder remains empty.

How can I expose the **jira-home** from inside the container to my host machine?

Thanks and best regards, Sebastian

Comment: How you access that folder? I have tried your configuration and everything seems fine at my side. I had only to modify access permission to `jira-home` after container start (otherwise I was no able to get into the folder)  because looks like docker-compose set some specific access to that mounted folder

Comment: I want to access the folder via the file manager. But I also expect jira to write files and folders to ./work/jira-home (so /var/atlassian/application-data/jira is created inside ./work/jira-home). The folder remains empty after starting the jira-container. Permissions look okay `drwxrwxrwx 1 pd03056 pd03056 4.0K Nov 11 10:35 work/`.

Comment: So you successfully open `./work/jira-home` with your file manager but there is no files there?

Comment: Yes exactly ... no files in `./work/jira-home`.

Comment: One information was missing: I'm using WSL on top of Windows 10

Comment: I tried on a normal linux mashine. I guess they're behaving the same. I discovered this on linux:

The dir `.work/jira-home` is created manually by me. Permissions are `drwx------ 9      2001      2001 4,0K Nov 11 13:04 jira-home/`.

After starting the container permissions are changed to `drwx------ 9      2001      2001 4,0K Nov 11 13:07 jira-home/`.

When I change my user to root, I can see all files and folders. Is there a way to access these files with my normal user? I guess and hope fixing on linux also fixes the issue for WSL.

Comment: yes, they are changed because docker runs on behalf of root. You need to change your dir to your project root and do `sudo chown -R ${USER}:${USER} ./work`

Comment: seems to work. thanks for your help. ... I ran `sudo chown -R ${USER}:${USER} ./work`and `
sudo chmod -R 777 ./work/jira-home`. But is there a way to force this behavior from my docker-compose.yml?

Comment: I don't think so